# Design Replication between 2 Always On Groups in SQL Server 2012

Tags: replication

I am using MS SQL Server 2012 version.
I have 2 Always on groups, 1 in DC and another in DR.
How can set up replication between a database with in DC and DR.

I studied that the Distributed Always on Availability Group is available only from 2016 version.

You help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

As a possible solution, you can look into creating failover cluster instances with SQL configured as the role (inside a failover cluster). Hopefully, this [link](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/high-availability-and-disaster-recovery-with-sql-alwayson-fci) will be helpful